# Expressing $*(z_1\wedge \bar z_2)$ without Hodge star operator

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry, exterior-algebra

I have been stuck on a computation for hours, and still cannot figure out where is the mistake:

For $2$-dimensional complex vector space, let $z_1,z_2$ be the basis. I want to compute $*(z_1\wedge \bar z_2)$. I am pretty sure the answer is $-z_2\wedge\bar z_1$. But if I write $z_1=x_1+iy_1$ and $z_2=x_2+iy_2$ then $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2$ is the standard basis. Then by the formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator#Computation_of_the_Hodge_star),
we have
\begin{equation}
*z_1\wedge \bar z_2\\
=*(x_1+iy_1)\wedge(x_2-iy_2)\\
=*(x_1\wedge x_2-ix_1\wedge y_2+i y_1\wedge x_2+y_1\wedge y_2)\\
=-y_1\wedge y_2-iy_1\wedge x_2+ix_1\wedge y_2-x_1\wedge x_2\\
=-(x_1+iy_1)\wedge (x_2-iy_2)\\
=-z_1\wedge \bar z_2
\end{equation}

which I also think is correct. So where is my mistake?

Comment: Why are you "pretty sure" that the answer is $-z_2 \wedge \bar z_1$?

Comment: @md2perpe Because I am pretty sure there is a formula $*(dz_I \wedge dz_J)=(\text{some coefficient})dz_{I^0}\wedge d\bar z_{J^0}$ where $I,J$ are any multi-indexes and $I^0$ is the complement of $I$.

Comment: @md2perpe there is a obvious typo in my last comment: the first $*(dz_I\wedge dz_J)$ should be $*(dz_I\wedge d\bar z_J)$.

Comment: But then you have just move "pretty sure" to the statement $*(dz_I \wedge d\bar z_J) \sim dz_{I^0} \wedge d\bar z_{J^0}.$ Why are you pretty sure about that?

Comment: @md2perpe Because I have used this formula for a long time. You can also read this on page $82$ of the book by Griffiths and Harris.

Comment: @md2perpe Also on compact manifold we have $(\alpha,\alpha)=\int \alpha\wedge * \alpha$, hence the computation above is certainly wrong.

Comment: That formula, when $\alpha$ is a complex differential form, shouldn't we either modify the formula to $(\alpha, \alpha) = \int \bar \alpha \wedge *\alpha$ or modify the definition of $*\alpha$ to take the complex conjugate of the coefficients? Perhaps that's the solution to this problem?

Comment: If $*\alpha$ takes the complex conjugate of the coefficients, then I get
$$*(dz_1 \wedge d\bar z_2) = - d\bar z_1 \wedge dz_2 = dz_2 \wedge d\bar z_1.$$

Comment: @md2perpe Oh I see! Thank you. You can post it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the formula $(\alpha,\alpha)=\int \alpha\wedge * \alpha$ to be valid for complex $\alpha$ we need a complex conjugation in the definition of $*\alpha$. Doing that we get
$$*(dz_1 \wedge d\bar z_2) = - d\bar z_1 \wedge dz_2 = dz_2 \wedge d\bar z_1.$$